# Getting stack overflow when trying to have the method repeat when there is an even number inputted

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
public static int rsnpeasant(int x, int y) {

  if ((y & 1) == 0) {
    y = y / 2;
    x = x * 2;
    rsnpeasant(x, y);
  } else {
    sum = sum + x;
    y = y / 2;
    y = y - 1 / 2;
    x = x * 2;

    if (y == 1) {
      sum = total;
      return total;

    } else {
      rsnpeasant(x, y);
    }
  }

  total = sum;
  return total;
}
```

The error is happening on the first `rsnpeasant(x,y);` line in the first `if` statement. It seems to be forever looping to that line even though it's supposed to go to the `else` statement if `y` is odd. If `y` is divided by `2` it should become odd at some point.
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html) is what im trying to code

Comment: Have you attempted to learn how to set breakpoints and debug the code?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: I think this line is wrong too, since it translate to y=y-0;

y = y - 1 / 2;

Comment: the y=y-1/2 is too get rid of the 0.5 when i divide an odd number by 2. not sure if it's still causing a problem though

Comment: What is rsnpeasant() trying to calculate?

Comment: Sorry i should have posted this, the code im writing is for this http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your principal problem is that you are trying to divide an int primitive type, if y = 1, dividing that value by 2 will return 0, then you pass it to the method again, it will always be stuck in the first if statement.

You should return a double, float or bigdecimal in your method, and use one of those types for the parameters too.

Comment: I love you so much, I added if(y==1){
    sum=sum+x;
    return sum;
} to the start of it and it worked right away

Answer (score 1):

`y=y-1/2`...

Order of operations will evaluate the `1/2` and subtract that from `y`.  In integer arithmetic, `1/2` is 0.  I think you want `y=(y-1)/2`.

Comment: well actually what i want to do is divide by 2 and drop the remainder. So I thought what would work is if it's an odd number and i divide by 2 I will always get .5 after, and subtracting 1/2 would be the same as dropping the remainder

Comment: @EvanBailey `0.5` doesn't exist in integer arithmetic. And since `y` is an integer, there is no remainder to drop. `5 / 2 == 2` in integer division. So you can just get rid of the subtraction altogether.